# JavaScript: Insert property into an object during loop

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm looping an array of objects taken from MongoDB and attempting to insert a property into one of them, without success.

The array of objects would be:

```
[
  {
    _id: [String],
    customerInformation: [ [Object] ],
    purchasedBanners: [ [Object] ],
    statusOfPurchase: 'new',
    createdAt: 2021-02-24T15:04:42.074Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-02-24T15:04:42.074Z,
    __v: 0
  }
  ...
]
```

I've tried:

```
return PurchasesModel.schemaForPurchases.find({
    statusOfPurchase: args.statusOfPurchase
  })
    .limit(10)
    .then(purchases => {
      purchases.forEach(purchase => {
        NotesModel.schemaForNotes.countDocuments({ purchaseId: purchase._id })
          .then(numberOfNotes => {
            Object.defineProperty(purchase, 'numberOfNotes', {
              value: numberOfNotes
            })
          })
      })
      return purchases
    })
```

But then I found that [the `forEach` method is synchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#description), so I tried:

```
return PurchasesModel.schemaForPurchases.find({
  statusOfPurchase: args.statusOfPurchase
})
  .limit(10)
  .then(purchases => {
    for (let i = 0; i < purchases.length; i++) {
      let numberOfNotes = 0
      numberOfNotes = NotesModel.schemaForNotes.countDocuments({ purchaseId: purchases[i]._id })
        .then(numberOfNotes => {
          return numberOfNotes
        })
        Object.defineProperty(purchases[i], 'numberOfNotes', {
          value: numberOfNotes.then(numberOfNotes => {
            return numberOfNotes
          })
        })
    }
    return purchases
  })
```

In each case (including several other approaches), the objects aren't appended.

I'm new to MongoDB, so I assume I'm either doing something wrong, or perhaps the objects are somehow protected?

Thoughts welcome.

Comment: I think you are returning purchases synchronously, before the promises inside the loops are resolved.

Comment: Yes, that was the case with the first attempt, and that's the reason I switched from `forEach` to `for`.

Comment: That dosen't help, for is also synchroneous.
I think You need this whole loop to return a promise or multiple promises instead

Comment: I don't know what mogo driver you use, but I'm fairly certain that your `purchases` variable does not contain an array of POJOs and thus `Object.defineProperty` won't work on them. Are you simply trying to add a new key (path) called `numberOfNotes` to all your docs? If so, does your schema allow that? Can you show your Purchases schema?

Comment: Yeah, I'm attempting to add `numberOfNotes` to each object. I was hoping this would work without me having to make changes to the schema, which doesn't allow for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, there wasn't a shortcut! Or at least I'm not aware of it.

```
const GET_ALL_PURCHASES_QUERY = (statusOfPurchase) => {
  return gql`
  query {
    getAllPurchases(statusOfPurchase: "${statusOfPurchase}") {
      id
      customerInformation {
        customerName
        customerEmailAddress
      }
      purchasedBanners {
        nameOfBanner
        costOfBanner
        numberOfBannersToPrint
        nameOfChosenComponent
        targetPDF
        previewImage
        dataToExport
      }
      numberOfNotes {
        count
      }
      createdAt
      updatedAt
    }
  }
```

... and then:

```
const NotesCountForPurchaseType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'NotesCountForPurchase',
  fields: () => ({
    count: {
      type: GraphQLInt
    }
  })
})

const PurchaseType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Purchase',
  fields: () => ({
    id: {
      type: GraphQLID
    },
    customerInformation: {
      type: GraphQLList(PurchaseCustomerInformationType)
    },
    purchasedBanners: {
      type: GraphQLList(PurchaseBannerType)
    },
    statusOfPurchase: {
      type: GraphQLString
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: GraphQLDateTime
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: GraphQLDateTime
    },
    numberOfNotes: {
      type: NotesCountForPurchaseType,
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return NotesModel.schemaForNotes.countDocuments({
          purchaseId: parent.id
        })
        .then(numberOfNotes => {
            console.log('Schema:numberOfNotes()', numberOfNotes)
            return { count: numberOfNotes }
          })
      }
    }
  })
})
```

Extra work, but working.